# How to set git-lfs as an additional checkout behavior using the JCAC plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jcac

We are using the Jenkins Configuration As Code (JCAC) plugin to automate the jenkins configuration. One of the challenges is to set `git-lfs` as an additional checkout behavior.

`GitLFSPull` has to be configured, but it does not seem to be included in the [DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob):

[image]

The README of the JCAC github repository indicates that support questions should be asked on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin?at=5d87457c5ab9361694381b5d)

According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961242/2777965), `GitLFSPull` should be an extension:

```
extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull']]
```

However, querying for this on [the Job DSL page](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-scm-git-extensions) shows that GitLFSPull seems to be omitted:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is only possible by using a workaround as depicted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637685/2777965).

After setting gitLFS in the UI, subsequently inspecting the `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/some-job/config.xml` file it became obvious that the XML looked as follows:

```
<traits>
   <jenkins.plugins.git.traits.GitLFSPullTrait>
      <extension class="hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.GitLFSPull"/>
   </jenkins.plugins.git.traits.GitLFSPullTrait>
</traits
```

After defining `jenkins.plugins.git.traits.GitLFSPullTrait`:

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      multibranchPipelineJob("example") {
        branchSources {
          ...
        }
        configure { node ->
          node / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits {
            'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.GitLFSPullTrait'()
          }
        }
      }
```

Git-lfs was enabled.