# How to set a shared-library globally using the JCAC plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jcac

This Q&A is related to [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9225/210) one and is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jenkins/jenkins.yaml

It should be possible by configuring it like this:

```
unclassified:
  globalLibraries:
    libraries:
      - name: "some-lib"
        retriever:
          modernSCM:
            scm:
              git:
                remote: "https://github.com/some-project.git"
                credentialsId: 'some-credentials'
```