# How to enable shallow clone using JCAC?

Tags: jenkins, jcac

Another question that is related to [this one](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9225/210). We try to configure the `shallow clone` using Jenkins Configuration As Code (JCAC). Although a configuration section is [available](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob-configure), `shallow clone` seems to be omitted:

[image]

[Gitter](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin?at=5d87457c5ab9361694381b5d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Jenkins Job DSL documentation](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-scm-git-extensions-cloneOptions-shallow) `shallow` has to be enabled:

```
shallow(true)
```

[image]